# Combine lists within a list based on conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a for loop to combine lists within a list based on criteria.

My dataset has 300 records of pets.  There are 3 types of animals (ex. dog, cat, bird), an interval for the year each animal was born (ex. (1990, 2000], (2000, 2004], etc.) and an interval for a friendly meter rating for each animal (ex. (0,2], (2, 4], (4, 6], etc.)

An example image of what the dataset may look like can be found here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwbGN.png

The current code I am using to combine the friendly meter ratings is below:

```
friendly_meter_combos = []
combo = []

for val in df['friendly_meter'].unique():
    if len(combo) < 2:
        combo.append(val)
    else:
        friendly_meter_combos.append(combo)
        combo = []
        combo.append(val)
```

This provides me with an example outcome for

```
friendly_meter_combos = 
[[(0, 2], (2, 4]],
 [(4, 6], (6, 8]],
 [(8, 10], (2, 4]], 
 [(4, 6], (6, 8]],
 ...].
```

As you can see in the second to last line I printed, the numbers start over ([(8, 10], (2, 4]]).  This is because I'm now on a different interval for the year born for the same animal type in the dataset.  I would like to figure out how to start the code over to get the output below instead

```
friendly_meter_combos = 
[[(0, 2], (2, 4]],
 [(4, 6], (6, 8]],
 [(8, 10]], 
 [(2, 4], (4, 6]],
 ...].
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What does the original data frame look like? You can get this by doing `df.head()`

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? 5 rows will do

Comment: Just added in a link with an image of the data.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand, you are looking to have a combination of consecutive "friendly meters"

```
# let's suppose unique_values is a list containing ordered friendly meters
unique_values = [ [0, 2], [2, 4], [4, 6], [6, 8], [8, 10] ]
# n is the size of the combo 
n = 2
# use statement below
friendly_meter_combos = list(zip(*(unique_values[i:] for i in range(n))))
```

Result is: 
[([0, 2], [2, 4]), ([2, 4], [4, 6]), ([4, 6], [6, 8]), ([6, 8], [8, 10])]

Comment: Hi Cherif, thank you for your answer.  I am actually looking to have the intervals start over once a new year_born interval begins.  In my actual dataset the intervals aren't as clean and very particular based on the type + year_born so I need the code to loop through those data points as conditionals to start the list of friendly_meter intervals over again, if that makes sense?

Comment: First of all, unqiue() methode doesn't produce ordered dataframe columns values. And are you sure that your df is ordered by "year" and "meter"
If you can tell me the purpose of friendly_meter_combos, maybe we can find another way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Thanks for asking! I did sort the df before running the loop, so it should go in order.  Overall, I am trying to combine bins to have 15 records within each type.  First I need to combine the friendly meter, then move into year_born.  For ex., if there is only 6 records that is a Type = Dog, year_born = (1990, 2000] and friendly meter=(0, 2] I want to combine with the next category that has 9 records of Type = Dog, year_born = (1990, 2000] and friendly meter=(2, 4] so that my new data is Type = Dog, year_born = (1990, 2000] and friendly meter=[(0, 4]] with 15 records in total.

Comment: Maybe, in this case, it would be better to groubBy your df by ( ["type", "year_born"] )  and then aggregate using an appropriate function to the group object.
[link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)